# Second router in another building

Tags: networking, router

I’ve bought a Technicolor router for my summer house like the one I have in the house.

Can it be plugged in the ONT box on the wall in anyone as the manual says port 1 but that one is for the house. Or can it be plugged into a LAN port in the house router?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a router in the house I would recommend using it as a switch and a WLAN access point. If you can set your router to "bridge mode" you should be all set, then you just need to plug it into a LAN port in the house and configure the WiFi.

If the router doesn't have "bridge mode" you need to disable DHCP on your router and make sure to use the router's LAN port (not the WAN port).

If you want to add a second router to your ONT you'll have to check with your provider. It depends on the setup but a common one is that your router will establish a PPPoE connection with your internet provider through the ONT and most providers don't allow multiple connections.

Comment: Okay thank you. I have tried this, however it conflicts with the house router. 
I’m not very tech savvy 

Comment: @karlpalmer I wasn't finished with the answer, make sure to read the update. The conflict is most likely because you still have DHCP enabled.

Comment: Okay sorry. 
Do I need to change the DHCP on the house router or the new one in the summer house? 
Will this effect the house router?

Comment: You need to turn off DCHP on the second/new router, you can't have two DHCP servers in one network.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot connect two routers to one ONT box. The router you connect to the ONT box is the single connection point to your provider. If you want to extend your Internet connection to a second building, use a switch which you connect to one of the LAN ports of your router.